# How can I display the files I have uploaded to a folder in my server on my website so that users can download them?

Tags: php, html, download

I have just created a webpage that allows users to upload files to a folder in my public_html folder.

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");`

I want to know if it is possible via php to create a webpage that displays the uploaded files from the folder I created in my public_html, so that they can be downloaded if needed?

Comment: just enable indexing for that particular directory using .htaccess.

Comment: You should not reinvent that wheel. There are good and secure solutions for that. Take a look at owncloud.org for example.

Comment: +1 to mr arkascha . There are too many security problems with "amateur" solutions to this.

Comment: I think a +1 comment would be the one that points out the security concerns beside directing him to his solution with an own coding effort. regards.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past:

```
$path = "/path/to/folder/";
$dir_handle = opendir($path);
echo "<ul>";
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
  if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != ".DS_Store") {
    if (!is_dir($file)) {
          echo "<li><a href='" . $file . "'>" . $file . "</a></li>";
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
```